# understanding output of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

.

```
for x in a and b:
        print(x)
```

Output: 6
7
8
9
10

```
for x in a or b:
    print(x)
```

Output: 1
2
3
4
5

Could someone please explain why this output is produced in these two instances.

Comment: What is the behaviour you're actually trying to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `a and b` evaluates the truthiness of the operands `a` and `b` and returns either the first operand that evaluates `False` or, if both operands evaluate `True`, the second operand:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] and []
[]
>>> [] and [1, 2, 3]
[]
>>> [] and ""
[]
>>> [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
```

`a or b` returns the first operand that evaluates `True` or, if both operands evaluate `False`, the second operand:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] or []
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [] or [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [] or ""
''
>>> [1, 2, 3] or [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
```

They are both *lazy*, giving up as soon as it can be determined for sure what the outcome will be. Note that empty containers `[]` and `""` evaluate `False`, whereas non-empy containers like `[1, 2, 3]` evaluate `True`.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
>>> a and b
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a or b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

the `and` operator will return `b` since it has to check both `a` and `b`. The `or` operator sees `a` as a value which isn't `False` thus immediately returning it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a or b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

[By definition](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html), `a or b` evaluates the truthiness of `a` and, if `a` is true, returns it (otherwise it returns `b`).

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator returns as soon as it finds the first `True` value.

```
>>> x = 1 or 2
>>> x
1
```

The `and` operator evaluates all the operands (in this case two operands) and returns only if all of them are `True`

```
>>> x = 1 and 6
>>> x
6
```

The for loop at each step assigns the comparison result to `x`. Hence in the first loop it gets the values of first list and in the second loop gets the values of second list as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `and` returns the last *truthy* (evaluates to `True`) operand if all are *truthy* otherwise it returns the first *falsey* (evaluates to `False`) operand.

Lists (with length > 0) are *truthy* regardless of the values in the list so the one to be iterated over depends solely on the oder:

```
>>> range(1,5) and range(6,10)
[6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(6,10) and range(1,5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Python's `or` returns the **first** *truthy* operand or the last operand if both are *falsey*. Again lists (with length > 0) are *truthy* so it's all about ordering here:

```
>>> range(1,5) or range(6,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(6,10) or range(1,5)
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```